# Is there a way to generate vault client tokens that don't expire at all?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm using https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/approle.html to generate vault client tokens,but I want them to never expire at all. Is that possible ?

Comment: Can't you set `token_ttl` and `token_max_ttl` or `period` to `0` when creating the app role? https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/approle.html#auth-approle-role-role_name-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in fact this is a Bad Idea(tm).  You can get close however.  You can set your max ttl's out to say 10 years, or something, and have it effectively not expire.  But, this is bad from a security perspective.  The goal here is, to be able to *easily* rotate secrets at any time.  I.e. you see someone stole the secret for a login, you should be able to very quickly and easily set a new password and your code/programs using those secrets should handle it, by just getting the new values from vault when their TTL expires.

This applies to *everything*, vault tokens included.

Comment: I get if the clients have a good Vault token, they can retrieve e.g. this login and password combination periodically. When it comes to the Vault token itself, this becomes difficult to achieve just with the Token auth method; I think it pushes for using other authentication methods but even the [AppRole](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/approle.html) page doesn't talk about leases and renewals.